# JavaScript function for the get the formatted date of tomorrow

Tags: javascript, algorithm, datetime

I need a JavaScript-function which **always** computes the date of the next day. Then returns the date as a string, formatted in the way: dd.mm.yyyy

I wrote this code:

```js
const getDateStringForTomorrow = () => {
    const millisOfDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const oTomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + millisOfDay);
    const day = ("0" + oTomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2);
    const month = ("0" + (oTomorrow.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const year = oTomorrow.getFullYear();

    return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
};

console.log(getDateStringForTomorrow());
```

**Can I expect my function to work as expected and to provide correct results?**

**What't your opinion about the way I have written the function? To you think it's overly verbose?**

Comment: Instead of adding a '0' and slicing, I might prefer `.toString().padStart(2, '0')` - I think it reads a little better.

Comment: Also, if accuracy matters, a day doesn't always have the same number of milliseconds (i.e. leap minutes). This would be an alternative way to get the next day: `oTomorrow = new Date(); oTomorrow.setDate(oTomorrow.getDate() + 1)` (setDate() will correctly handle too-large numbers)

Comment: @Scotty Jamison I have seen the technique you are mentioning, in an article: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-get-tomorrow-date-javascript/ Now, it becomes clear to me, why they are doing it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#datetimeformat-objects) you can also format the date elements to 2 and 4 digits. You code would then look something like this:

```
const getDateStringForTomorrow = () => {
  const tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  const day   = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(tomorrow);
  const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: '2-digit' }).format(tomorrow);
  const year  = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(tomorrow);
  return day + '.' + month + '.' + year;

};

console.log(getDateStringForTomorrow());
```

Another variant uses the European date format to get the order of the elements correctly and then only replaces dashes by dots:

```
const getDateStringForTomorrow = () => {
  const tomorrowDate = new Date();
  tomorrowDate.setDate(tomorrowDate.getDate() + 1);
  const tomorrowStr = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('uk', { day: '2-digit',  month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }).format(tomorrow);
  return tomorrowStr.replaceAll('-','.');

};

console.log(getDateStringForTomorrow());
```

The advantage of using `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` is that it writes out very clearly what you want.